# Flutter Navigation with values between different screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I would be very grateful if someone could explain how to deal with the following problem:

I have a screen with 2 fields which redirect me to 2 different pages. On each of these pages I have a text field that uses a controller to push the text into the field on the previous page.

However, I don't have a solution for this, because when I work with Navigator.push one field is always empty. If I work with Navigator.pop, I cannot transfer any data (can I?).

**Is there any possibility to use Navigator.pop and pass some data or something like that?**

Comment: Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the sections on [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get results from your second screen with waiting on push

here is an example:

you call this in first page

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
    )
  );
```

and In your second screen, when you are calling pop, pass data to it, like this:

```
Navigator.pop(context, controller.text);
```

then in your first page, you have controller text in result variable

Comment: happy to help out :)